# Select substring with dashes in SQL

Tags: sql, string, count, aggregate-functions

I have this column called `package_type` and it contains strings like this:

```
TP-CYS01-01-2700-W-003
TP-CYS01-01-2700-W-004
TP-CYS01-02-2700-W-003
TP-CYS01-02-2700-W-001
```

I need to count the `package_type` but grouped by the `package_no` which is `CYS01-01`, `CYS01-02`.

What I have done is this:

```
select 
    substring(substring(package_type, '-', 3), '-', -2) as package_no,
    count(distinct package_type)
from
    project_june 
where 
    progress = bill_of_quantity and event_date = '2020-06-12'
group by 
    substring(substring(package_type, '-', 3), '-', -2) as package_no
```

I get this error:

> Invalid input syntax for integer: "-"

I expect the result would be like:

```
package_no   count
------------------
CYS01-01      2
CYS01-02      2
```

How am I suppose to write this query?

Thank you.

Comment: You can't define a column alias in the GROUP BY clause. Skip the AS ... part-

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: i remove the AS, still error

Comment: Wong type of argumenst: `substring(string, integer, integer)`

Comment: When you write your queries, take smaller steps. When the first substring works, add the second. Then add group by etc.

Comment: ```substring_index(substring_index(test_package, '-', 3), '-', -2)```  here's my substring query

Comment: The second argument should be an integer. `substring(string, startposition, numberofcharacters)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your strings seem to have a fixed format -- and you want 8 characters starting at the 4th position.  That suggests that you can use:

```
select substring(package_type, 4, 8), as package_no,
       count(distinct package_type)
from project_june 
where progress = bill_of_quantity and
      event_date = '2020-06-12'
group by substring(package_type, 4, 8);
```

There are no doubt other ways to write such a query.  However, string functions are often database-specific and your question doesn't specify what database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that you are running Postgres. That database has powerful string functions - you can just use `split_part()`:

```
select split_part(package_no, '-', 2) as package_no, count(distinct package_type) as cnt
from project_june 
where progress = bill_of_quantity and event_date = date '2020-06-12'
group by split_part(package_no, '-', 2)
```

Notes:

- Presumably, `event_date` is of a `date`-like datatype, so it should be compared against a literal date rather than a string.
- I am suspicious about condition `progress = bill_of_quantity`; is `bill_of_quantity` an actual column in your table? If it is meant to be a literal string instead, then it should be surrounded with single quotes